# how to map combination keys Fn+Fx to other keys in win10 without any 3rd-party application

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, windows-registry, keymap

I tried to map the total twelve `Fn`+`Fx` combination keys on my A4Tech kv-300 USB keyboard, like `Fn`+`F12`, to other keys, like `enter` key, in win10 according to Microsoft's doc but failed, although other maps, like mapping `alt` to `enter`, works.

According to [Microsoft's doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/keyboard-and-mouse-class-drivers#scan-code-mapper-for-keyboards) about configuration of keyboard and mouse class drivers, registry value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\Scancode Map` can be used to remap key. I tested the demo in that doc and everything is fine.

Then I tried to map `Fn`+`Fx` to `enter`. As an example, I'll explain what I've tried for `Fn`+`F12` in order.

1. Identify the scan code of `Fn`+`F12`.

   The function of `Fn`+`F12` on A4Tech kv-300 keyboard is open/close favorites in IE browser, meanwhile there is only one entry about favorites in Microsoft's doc [USB HID to PS/2 Scan Code Translation Table](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/translate.pdf), which is listed in [Remarks on RAWKEYBOARD structure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawkeyboard#remarks). According to that table, the scan code of `WWW Favorites` is 0xE066. I also tested `Fn`+`F12` via [script of AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/103748-help-please-with-remap-fnpgup-to-home-on-thinkpad/?p=639372), which showed that the scan code of `Fn`+`F12` was 0x166, representation of 0xE066 in AutoHotkey.
2. Edit registry `Scancode Map`.

   I changed my registry entry `Scancode Map` to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ4wR.png). After reboot, nothing changed. The function of `Fn`+`F12` was still opening/closing favorites in IE browser. And the script of AutoHotkey above showed that the scan code of `Fn`+`F12` was still 0xE066.

I've also tried the same thing for other eleven combination keys `Fn`+`Fx`. In all of those cases, change to registry entry `Scancode Map` made no difference. All of those combination keys still did the same work as before instead of doing `enter` job.

Then I get couple of questions.

1. Is it possible to map `Fn`+`Fx` to `enter` or any other keys on A4Tech kv-300 keyboard in win10 via registry? If it's possible, how? If it's impossible, why? And is there any alternative independent of 3rd-party applications?
2. Is the scan code of `Fn`+`F12` on A4Tech kv-300 keyboard still 0xE066? According to its function and the script of AutoHotkey above, I guess it is. If it is, why the change to registry makes no difference? Or maybe A4Tech kv-300 keyboard installed some special driver on my win10 OS according to [Microsoft's doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/keyboard-and-mouse-hid-client-drivers)?

EDIT:

I finally understand what happens to `Fn`+`Fx` on my USB keyboard kv-300 and why registry doesn't work for them.

1. My guess.

   According to Microsoft's doc [Keyboard and mouse HID client drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/keyboard-and-mouse-hid-client-drivers), there are two possible flow ways for the HID Usage ID transmitted by USB keyboard. One is

   ```
   hidclass.sys --> kbdhid.sys --> kbdclass.sys
   ```

   labelled with 'Keyboard', and the other is

   ```
   hidclass.sys --> hidserv.dll
   ```

   labelled with 'Hot Buttons'. Only via `kbdhid.sys`, i.e. in the 1st way, can HID Usage ID be translated to PS/2 Set 1 code, i.e. scan code which can be remapped via registry as above. So I think that HID Usage ID's of `Fn`+`Fx` transmitted by my keyboard possibly flow in the 2nd way and are processed as 'Hot Buttons', which means that they flow to `hidserv.dll` directly without being translated to scan code, resulting from which registry as above can't intervene and don't work.
2. Corroborate my guess.

   In device manager, I find my kv-300 keyboard device, `Keyboards\HID Keyboard Device`, whose 'Driver Details' shows two dependency drivers, `kbdhid.sys` and `kbdclass.sys`. After uninstalling this device, all keys including combination keys on my keyboard don't work any more, except all `Fn`+`Fx` combination keys. That means that all `Fn`+`Fx` combination keys don't flow in the 1st way as above, so they can only flow in the 2nd way.

So my question changed to:

1. How to redirect keyboard signals, used to be transferred in the 1st way, to the 2nd path as above without any 3rd-party application?
2. If that's impossible, then is it possible to have a hand in the 'Hot Buttons' path as above without any 3rd-party application? If it's possible, then how to map combination keys `Fn`+`Fx` to other keys?

Comment: See if your BIOS maps these keys - common.

Comment: @John Thx for your advice. How to check that? My motherboard is MPG B550 GAMING PLUS. I once walked through its bios settings and don't remember that there is any option about keymap.

Comment: There may not be such options in your BIOS. I was just asking to check. Otherwise if Auto Hotkey won't remap, I am not sure. I will look around.